# Java - using Socket with Proxy

Tags: java, sockets, networking, proxy

I am using sockets to connect to websites and APIs via HTTP (I know, this could be done easier with the URL class, but I had some reasons for choosing this way).

Now I want to implement a privacy feature, and so all the connections should be redirected through a proxy. But I am running into problems doing that.

I looked for and selected a free proxy, for testing purposes, from a [Free Proxy List](http://www.freeproxylists.net/) website. I chose one with a high uptime for my testing routines, but it hasn't worked out so far.

My source code:

```
URL url = new URL("someurl");
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("202.77.110.22", 8080); 
java.net.Proxy javaProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, address);
Socket server = new Socket(javaProxy);
server.connect(new InetSocketAddress(url.getHost(), url.getPort()));
```

I want to connect to the URL via the proxy "202.77.110.22:8080". If I execute the code using Eclipse, I have to wait approximately five minutes and then receive the following error:

> SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server

When using Proxy.Type.HTTP instead of Proxy.Type.SOCKS, I receive the following error message:

> IllegalArgumentException - Invalid Proxy

I know that (forms of) this question have already been asked on Stackoverflow, but none of the answers have helped me. Maybe I chose an unsupported proxy? It works while testing it using Apache HttpComponents.

All help appreciated.

Comment: execepthe last line which I changed to server.connect(new InetSocketAddress(url.getHost(), (url.getPort()==-1)?80:url.getPort())); Your code works in my machine

Comment: Have you checked that the proxy works by setting it in your browser?

Comment: The proxy works using Apache HttpComponents. @OmarMEBARKI I tried it, but I still got the same error - I have to wait 5 min and then receive a SocketException. My full code: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5616412/ Can you post your full code and your output?

Comment: I am sorry, Actually it doesnot work. It cannot work because a socket needs only an IP adress. But an URL can have IP + file name ...

Comment: 8080 will be an HTTP proxy, not a SOCKS proxy, as the first exception indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Java 8, raw **TCP socket** connectivity only works through SOCKS proxies - that's why you got [`IllegalArgumentException - Invalid Proxy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html). It was only in Java 8 that connection of raw sockets through HTTP proxies was added.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to get rid of this line:

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("202.77.110.22", 8080);
```

And change this line:

```
java.net.Proxy javaProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, address);
```

to:

```
java.net.Proxy javaProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, "202.77.110.22:8080");
```

Because you can't specify a proxy as a "InetSocketAddress". Those are two different things.